# Error setting up a Trigger.io for an Android app on a mac

Tags: android, macos, trigger.io

I am just beginning to work with Trigger.io on my Mac. Unfortunately I hitting an error when  I am to setting up a test Android app. I able to get a web app to build but I am getting the following error when building for android.

[ERROR] failed: Error: Target id is not valid. Use 'android list targets' to get the target ids.

My andriod sdk is in /Applications/android-sdk-macosx and should be working.

If anyone can help it would be much appreciated,

Thanks guys,

kSeudo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have seen this problem once before, and are trying to get to the bottom of how the particular setup is causing it - it does not affect all users.

The workaround for now is to either use an actual device for testing, or create and start an AVD manually before using 'forge run android'. You can create AVDs using the AVD manager. To open it up, run 'android' at the command-line and select Tools->Manage AVDs. There are further instructions here:

http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds.html

Comment: Great thanks Amir,

I have the app running on the emulator and my phone. Trigger.io has really impressed me so far.

thanks again,

kSeudo.

Comment: I've been trying to get an app working locally on my Nexus 7 and am hitting this same issue.